# alternative way to traverse through json lists of lists of lists in apex

Tags: rest-api, json, apexrest, jsongenerator

I have the attached json structure and just wondering is there a better way to traverse through the items to obtain them ? whatever i am doing is working and is shown below , but just would like to know what if the depth of json goes more deep, lets say 2 to 5 (list of list of list of list) , does that mean i would need to have 7-8 levels of, for loop depth ? please let me know

```
{
"name": "dsadasadsdfasdas",
"id": "3a314b65-47ee-47d8-b51f-8cdeefb0861b",
"status": "Draft",
"items": [{
    "item_types": [{
        "item_Groups":[
            {  
                "name":"display",       
                "properties": [{
                    "name":"label",
                    "value":"submit",
                    "property_uuid":"kjahdsa",
                    "picklist_options": [
          {
            "label": "CAr",
            "value": "audi"
          },
          {
            "label": "car1",
            "value": "bmw"
          },
          {
            "label": "car3",
            "value": "hyu"
          },
          {
            "label": "car4",
            "value": "inf"
          }
        ],
        "item_options": [
          {
                     "options": [
              {
                "label": "rolls",
                "value": "royce"
              },
              {
                "label": "aston",
                "value": "martin"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]

                }]
            }
         ],
        "name": "",
        "type": "Page",
        "itemid": 97856
    }],
    "item_input": false,
    "value": null,
    "order": 0,

    "id": "f2b2bbec-da2a-4812-9eeb-623938c9c393",
    "name": "rc"
},
```

Apex Code:

```
 for (List <types> itemtypelist: ParentUUIDChildStdTypeMap.keyset()) {

        for (types itemType: itemtypelist) {

        for (item_groups pg: itemType.item_Groups) {

                for (properties prop: pg.properties) {
                       for (associate_options ao: prop.associate_options) {
```

Comment: you can see the traversing , i went through 1)multiple depth for loops 2)untyped deserialization but again thats going through such iterative fashion as well

Comment: It really depends what you're doing with the data. You can access this information using nested loops; you can extract each level of data and call a separate method; you can unroll nested loops; you can choose to store data directly without traversing it. Could you add more specifics to your question about what you want to do? It's hard to answer in the hypothetical case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there aren't any other viable options.

Nested structures *require* loops (or recursion) at some point, and [x] levels of nested structure need [x] levels of nested loop. There's just no way to avoid it.

I'd say that loops are preferred over recursion here, because with recursion you have the overhead related to a method call (evaluate arguments, push stack frame, etc...) whereas loops just become (relatively) simple jumps.